# How do I run a job every 2 months

Tags: c#

I have to filter the jobs to be run today based on the date. So, for every scheduled date, I am comparing it to DateTime.Today.Date and getting a list of jobs that are scheduled to run today. 
How can I filter the recurring job based on the given cycle time? 
Example:
->If cycle time is 0, run every month on the scheduled date.
->If cycle time is 2, for the first time run the job on scheduled day and then run every two months.

I have to add cycle time in this way, if schedule date = 3/7/2016, cycle time =2, and if scheduled date == today, run service and add 2 months(5/7/2016) and run service on that date and add 2 months(7/7/2016) and so on.
I wrote this way, but if it once returns true it is not checking the other condition. And this is not working for my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Quartz job schedular. It uses Cron-Expressions for scheduling.

Cron-Expressions are used to configure instances of CronTrigger. Cron-Expressions are strings that are actually made up of seven sub-expressions, that describe individual details of the schedule. These sub-expression are separated with white-space, and represent:

```
1. Seconds
2. Minutes
3. Hours
4. Day-of-Month
5. Month
6. Day-of-Week
7. Year (optional field)
```

An example of a complete cron-expression is the string "0 0 12 ? * WED" - which means "every Wednesday at 12:00 pm".

tutorials are available at http://simplequartzschedulerincsharp.blogspot.in/